# Unable to add or move components in Experience Editor

Tags: experience-editor, components

After an upgrade from 7.2 to 9.0.2, we are facing a weird issue in Experience Editor with few of our components.

On few of the pages we are unable to add/move/delete components using experience editor. We do not see the Context Menu which normally appears when we select a component on the experience editor like below:

[image]

We observed that the Designing CheckBox is disabled under VIEW menu. Which is preventing the items to move/add/delete on the experience editor.

What could be the possible reason having the *Designing* checkbox unchecked for few content items in Experience Editor? Even if we try to select it manually we are unable to move components.

[image]

It is working on v7.2 for same content item but not on v9.0.2. What is missing?

Answer (score 2):

Post analysis and confirming that there is nothing wrong at the code/project side, we decided to raise a Sitecore Support ticket for the this experience. Later on the support team identified it as a BUG in Sitecore.

This weird experience was due to an issue with improper parsing and double quotes, which was registered as a bug in their bug tracking system. As expected in such scenarios they provided us a patch to be installed on XP 9.0.2, which fixed the issue.

Please use the link below to download the patch fixing the issue:

https://sitecore.box.com/s/gv0kb1594d9dg2sscvk5lgz87fdo7px3

More information about Sitecore patches can be found here:

https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/077333